# GCP-terraform deleting roles but not re-creating(1.20)

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp

Good Day.Hope you are doing good.

Can you please help to fix this...

When we add a new role(ex: roles/pubsub.admin) to the existing group, terraform deletes and recreates the existing roles of the group if any due to us treating the roles as a list. Behind the scenes they are being stored in an indexed list, so inserting a role in the middle of the list causes the index to change for all roles after it but end results should be same.

in a few cases, terraform is failed to recreate the deleted roles.  for ex: roles/errorreporting.admin is the existing role and terraform deleted this role but failed to recreate it(by the time terraform execution was completed).

So to resolve this, every time we had to run the plan and apply 2 times for each application. Not sure this is the correct way to proceed

> **Note**: We integrated terraform with cloud build.